CSS not updating the Navbar React Element
I am starting out with a fresh react app. I have created the Navbar.js element which contains the semantic HTML5 structure for the Nav Element. I've also created the styles.css in order to give a style to the Nav Element.
After that, on index.js, I have imported the following: import"./styles.css";
Eventhough, it seems that I did it on the right way, my local host doesn't display any updates.
I have deleted the styles.css file and created it again. I have also tried to generated another import"./styles.css"; on index.js.
I was expecting to have navbar.js UI updated as I have created a css style for it.

Hi, I'd love to help you out. Can you provide some code snippets from your Navbar.js, index.js, and styles.css files so I can understand the problem better?
